# Search Array & Return All Keys & Value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on array similar to this :

```
$users = array(    
    array( 'name' => "John", 'lastname' => 'doe'),
    array( 'name' => "smith", 'lastname' => 'Jones'),
);
```

I want to search in array by "name" & return its "lastname"

Example : I have "john" as name & while searching array I want "Doe" as return value.

I have tried following function but

```
function my_function( $array, $name ) {
        foreach( $array as $name ) {
            .....
        }
}

my_function($users, 'John');
```

but I get "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" Error.

What is correct way of doing it?

Comment: The bits and pieces of code you show should work fine. There's an error in some part you're not showing. Reusing the variable `$name` is a problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is the double use of $name

With the following code I get "doe" when input is "John"

```
$users = array(    
    array( 'name' => "John", 'lastname' => 'doe'),
    array( 'name' => "smith", 'lastname' => 'Jones'),
);

function my_function( $array, $name ) {
  foreach( $array as $row ) {
      if($row['name'] == $name) {
        return $row['lastname'];
      }
  }
}

echo my_function($users, 'John');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_function( $array, $name, $haystackkey, $returnkey) {

    foreach( $array as $key => $item ) {
        if (isset($item[$haystackkey]) && $item[$haystackkey] == $name) {
            return $item[$returnkey];
        }            
    }

}
```

Call

```
my_function ($array, 'John', 'name', 'lastname');
```

This will search $array for an element where 'name' is 'John', and will return the value og 'lastname'. Of course you can hardcode the last 2 parameters, if not used in other context.

**Beware** that this will only return the **first occurence**. To get a list or results, replace `return` by `$result[]=...`.

Answer (score 0):

Yay for array reduction. Not the most efficient method, but cool.

```
$found = array_reduce($users, function ($found, array $candidate) use ($name) {
    return $found ?: ($candidate['name'] == $name ? $candidate['lastname'] : null);
});
```

Comment: That **is** cool. However, it´s a pain to understand and even more to adapt or reuse, left alone the performance nightmare - so I would never use it in production code. Anyway, nice code :)

Comment: I at least have to flex my fingers a little with these array iteration questions... ;) And for small arrays, the performance really isn't "nightmarish". Using Functional PHP, I'd do something like `F\first($users, function ($u) use ($name) { return $u['name'] == $name; })['lastname']`, just because it's so small I don't have to create a new function for it... :)

Comment: I assume you have some solid C++ background? PHP folks tend write code that is far less elegant and way longer than yours, but does not feel like a handstand on a chainsaw :)

Comment: Nope, none actually. I have a secret love affair with Haskell though. Which may be even more destructive to my PHP foo than C... ;)